# example of KeyboardwillHide notification

Tags: uitextfield

Can somebody post the code (simple one) which shows the use of KeyboardwillhideNotification ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple [UICatalog sample program](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/UICatalog/Listings/TextViewController_m.html) has an example.